# Tab bar missing when a segue is added

Tags: ios, swift

So I have 3 VCs embedded in a navigation controller and a tab bar controller. However, whenever I add a segue from the 3rd VC to the 1st VC, the navigation bar and tab bar disappear from the storyboard. So I tried adding a segue programmatically on the 3rd VC swift file as such:

```
let collectionVC = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "collectionVC") as! CollectionViewController

    let navigationVC = UINavigationController(rootViewController: collectionVC)
    self.present(navigationVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Unfortunately, with the added code above, the tab bar is still missing but the navigation bar is there. I hope someone could help me.

Comment: What directly you want to archive? You want to have one tabbar in your app with three different Navigationscontrollers or you want to have three different tabbars?

Comment: If I'm correct, you are trying to go from 3rd VC to 1st VC: why don't use "navigationController?.popToRootViewControllerAnimated(true)" ? You will have tab bar, navigation bar and - most important - you won't create another instance of 1st VC

Comment: @MarcoPace Thanks! It worked :)

Comment: I will convert it to a answer then, might be useful for others :).

Comment: You must share more code in order for us to get in context. I'm almost sure you're creating new instances everytime you're moving from a VC to another instead of working with the ones you already have

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood correctly your problem, you are using a `UINavigationController` and you are trying to go from **VC3** to **VC1**, which means that you have a navigation stack like this:

> VC1 -> VC2 -> VC3

If you want to go back to VC1, you can use:

```
navigationController?.popToRootViewControllerAnimated(true)‌​
```

You will still have your tab bar, your navigation bar and - most important - you won't create another instance of **VC1**. This is the correct - and easiest - way of dealing with a `UINavigationController`.